# How to chain Swift Futures

Tags: swift, functional-programming, combine

I have defined the following functions:

```
func createAccessControl() -> Future<SecAccessControl, Error>

func evaluatePolicy(context: LAContext, localizedReason: String) -> Future<LAContext, Error>

func evaluateAccessControl(
    context: LAContext,
    accessControl: SecAccessControl,
    operation: LAAccessControlOperation,
    localizedReason: String
) -> Future<LAContext, Error>

func copy(query: [String: Any]) -> Future<Data, Error>
```

And I want to chain them together like this:

```
func load(key: String, context: LAContext = LAContext(), localizedReason: String) -> Future<Data, Error> {
        createAccessControl().flatMap { accessControl in
            evaluatePolicy(context: context, localizedReason: localizedReason)
                .flatMap { context in
                    evaluateAccessControl(context: context, accessControl: accessControl, operation: .useItem, localizedReason: localizedReason)
                }
                .flatMap { context in
                    copy(query: [
                        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
                        kSecAttrService as String: service,
                        kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
                        kSecAttrAccessControl as String: accessControl,
                        kSecUseAuthenticationContext as String: context,
                        kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
                        kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
                    ])
                }
        }
    }
```

However, I get this error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Publishers.FlatMap<Publishers.FlatMap<Future<Data, Error>, Publishers.FlatMap<Future<LAContext, Error>, Future<LAContext, Error>>>, Future<SecAccessControl, Error>>' to return type 'Future<Data, Error>'
```

I thought `flatMap` was supposed to flatten the resulting type, but that doesn't seem to be happening the way I expect.

How do I chain futures together, similar to JavaScript's "then"?

Comment: Flatten doesn't flatten the type of the publisher, nay, it actually complicates it (by introducing a wrapping type, as you see). It flattens the *`Output`* of the publisher.

Comment: @Alexander Okay thanks, I've rephrased my question. Isn't there a sane way to chain futures together, without nesting, like JavaScript's then?

Comment: Swift's (well, Combine's, technically) Futures are quite different from Javascripts. I think some of the confusion here is coming from the expectations/experience you're bringing in from Javascript, that don't apply in Swift. Future's are like the "bridge" into Combine's land of publishers. `Just`, `Empty` and `Failure` are other examples of such "bridges". You use a Future in order to convert a function that takes a completion handler, into one that returns a publisher. Once you're in Publisher land, you chain operators to get other Publisher, not specifically futures.

Comment: The common currency of deferral/asynchronous work in Combine is `AnyPublisher<Value, Error>`. It's fine if you have a private function that returns a `Future<T, E>`, a `Just<T>`, etc. here and there, but generally you want your public APIs to return `AnyPublisher<Value, Error>` by using `.eraseToAnyPublisher()`, so that your API doesn't make guarantees about the concrete publishers you use in your pipelines.

Comment: What I had intended was to be able to break the asynchronous work into pieces, then chain them together in a function that returns the type I want. But it sounds like I should probably just rewrite these functions to use completion handlers, and only convert into a Future when I need to inject it into a publisher pipeline.

Comment: Uhhhh, what? How did anything I just said make you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Are you saying I just need to change my function return types from Future<Output, Failure> to AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>?

Comment: At the public API boundaries, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my return types from `Future<>` to `AnyPublisher<>` eliminated all the compiler errors, and simply required a call to `eraseToAnyPublisher()` inside those functions. For example:

```
func evaluateAccessControl(context: LAContext, accessControl: SecAccessControl, operation: LAAccessControlOperation, localizedReason: String) -> AnyPublisher<LAContext, Error> {
    Future() { promise in
        context.evaluateAccessControl(accessControl, operation: operation, localizedReason: localizedReason) { success, error in
            if let error = decodeLAError(error) {
                promise(.failure(error))
            } else if success {
                promise(.success(context))
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Yep, looks good. Though I wouldn't `eraseToAnyPublisher()` too often/early, because it causes allocations and it's opaque to the optimizer. If this is a private helper function, I would keep the `Future` return type, and only erase at the public interface boundaries